# Pass Attribute Metadata of Properties Directly &Programmaticly to Html Helper Methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

We can decorate the properties of a model class with attributes, like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // other properties are skipped
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

And if you call the build-in Html helper methods such as Html.TextBoxFor()/Html.TextBox() in views, they can automatically grab the metadata from the attributes, and generate HTML markups accordingly, for example, the calls:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 ">
    @Html.Label("First Name", @Model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7">
    @Html.TextBox("FirstName", @Model.FirstName )
    @Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName", "", null)
</div>
```

will give you a piece of HTML that implements client validation, which means if user leaves the textbox empty, a validation message will show up.

However, because I have a group of dynamic fields associated with my model class, generated from database, I simply cannot decorate them with attributes. So, my question is, can I call TextBox(), passing the attribute metadata explicitly and programmaticly, and so that it generates the HTML as if the property was decorated with [Required]?

In one word, I need to programmaticly instruct helper methods directly as if they were getting the instructions from attribute metadata.

I walked through its [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) page, and did not find any clue. If I cannot do that, I probably need to override TextBox(), and then what is the best way to do it? Please kindly note that I will use TextBox() instead of strongly typed methods.

**More background information:**

I have a VM class for dynamic field defined as:

```
public class DynmFldViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DataType { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

And let's suppose I have some of such dynamic fields associated with a Product entity, so behind my product editing view, I have a view model defined as:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    // other properties are skipped
    public List<DynmFldViewModel> fields  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: IMHO you need to create [Custom HTML helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Comment: Short answer is no, because you not adding attributes to properties so no metatdata is applied to the property (other than those implied by the property type and value) so the `HtmlHelper` method has nothing to read

Comment: For the `Required` condition, you could always decorate the `Name` property your binding to with a conditional attribute (e.g. a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue("IsRequired ", ErrorMessage = Please enter a name")]` attribute (or write your own)

Comment: Thank you all. Yeah, @StephenMuecke, you r right, if we still rely on attributes, it is impossible. So I was wondering if the framework provides a mechanism to allow me to bypass the attributes and instruct the helper methods directly. I prefer this approach is because the behavior I need of helper methods has already been provided by those built-in methods.

Comment: No it does not.